# How do I use colormaps with variable alpha in a kdeplot without seeing the contour lines?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, kdeplot

Python version: 3.6.4 (Anaconda on Windows)
Seaborn: 0.8.1
Matplotlib: 2.1.2

I'm trying to create a 2D Kernel Density plot using Seaborn but I want each step in the colourmap to have a different alpha value. I had a look at this question to create a matplotlib colourmap with alpha values: [Add alpha to an existing matplotlib colormap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327308/add-alpha-to-an-existing-matplotlib-colormap).

I have a problem in that the lines between contours are visible. The result I get is here: [image: Visible contour lines in a Seaborn kdeplot]

I thought that I had found the answer when I found this question: [Hide contour linestroke on pyplot.contourf to get only fills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263769/hide-contour-linestroke-on-pyplot-contourf-to-get-only-fills). I tried the method outlined in the answer (using `set_edgecolor("face")` but it did not work in this case. That question also seemed to be related to vector graphics formats and I am just writing out a PNG.

Here is my script:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.colors as cols
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def alpha_cmap(cmap):
    my_cmap = cmap(np.arange(cmap.N))
    # Set a square root alpha.
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, cmap.N)
    my_cmap[:,-1] = x ** (0.5)
    my_cmap = cols.ListedColormap(my_cmap)

    return my_cmap

xs = np.random.uniform(size=100)
ys = np.random.uniform(size=100)

kplot = sns.kdeplot(data=xs, data2=ys,
                    cmap=alpha_cmap(plt.cm.viridis),
                    shade=True,
                    shade_lowest=False,
                    n_levels=30)

plt.savefig("example_plot.png")
```

Guided by some comments on this question I have tried some other methods that have been successful when this problem has come up. Based on this question ([Matplotlib Contourf Plots Unwanted Outlines when Alpha < 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192661/matplotlib-contourf-plots-unwanted-outlines-when-alpha-1)) I have tried altering the plot call to:

```
sns.kdeplot(data=xs, data2=ys,
            cmap=alpha_cmap(plt.cm.viridis),
            shade=True,
            shade_lowest=False,
            n_levels=30,
            antialiased=True)
```

With `antialiased=True` the lines between contours are replaced by a narrow white line:

[image: Visible contour lines in a Seaborn kdeplot with antialiasing]

I have also tried an approach similar to this question - [Pyplot pcolormesh confused when alpha not 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678817/pyplot-pcolormesh-confused-when-alpha-not-1). This approach is based on looping over the `PathCollections` in `kplot.collections` and tuning the parameters of the edges so that they become invisible. I have tried adding this code and tweaking the linewidth -

```
for thing in kplot.collections:
    thing.set_edgecolor("face")
    thing.set_linewidth(0.01)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

This results in a mix of white and dark lines - [image: Visible contour lines in a Seaborn kdeplot].

I believe that I will not be able to tune the line width to make the lines disappear because of the variable width of the contour bands.

Using both methods (antialiasing + linewidth) makes this version, which looks cool but isn't quite what I want: 
[image: Visible contour lines in a Seaborn kdeplot]

I also found this question - [Changing Transparency of/Remove Contour Lines in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767891/changing-transparency-of-remove-contour-lines-in-matplotlib?rq=1)

This one suggests overplotting a second plot with a different number of contour levels on the same axis, like:

```
kplot = sns.kdeplot(data=xs, data2=ys,
                    ax=ax,
                    cmap=alpha_cmap(plt.cm.viridis),
                    shade=True,
                    shade_lowest=False,
                    n_levels=30,
                    antialiased=True)

kplot = sns.kdeplot(data=xs, data2=ys,
                    ax=ax,
                    cmap=alpha_cmap(plt.cm.viridis),
                    shade=True,
                    shade_lowest=False,
                    n_levels=35,
                    antialiased=True)
```

This results in:
[image: Visible contour lines in a Seaborn kdeplot - double plot]

This is better, and almost works. The problem here is I need variable (and non-linear) alpha throughout the colourmap. The variable banding and lines seem to be a result of the combinations of alpha when contours are plotted over each other. I also still see some clear/white lines in the result.

Comment: I think I remember there being a question an that topic where the solution is to set the linewidth of the contour patches to a specific value. Maybe you can find that question and apply it here.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - I've had a look around and I think this seems the closest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003353/why-does-my-colorbar-have-lines-in-it. I've tried looping over the `PathCollections` in `kplot.collections` and call `set_edgecolor("face")` and `set_linewidth(0.000001)`. This gets closer, but the lines never disappear completely and sometimes the individual contours seem to start overlapping.

Comment: [This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678817/pyplot-pcolormesh-confused-when-alpha-not-1) I was remembering, where the soluton would be to use `linewidth=0.0015625`. There is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192661/matplotlib-contourf-plots-unwanted-outlines-when-alpha-1) which proposes `antialiased=True`. For [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090563/in-python-how-can-i-inherit-and-override-a-method-on-a-class-instance-assignin?noredirect=1&lq=1) `linewidth=0.2` seems enough.

Comment: It would be good it this question could incorporate those attempts and show in how far they would not work.