# Aliasing when saving matplotlib surface plot to .pdf

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I save a 3d surface plot to `.pdf` with `linewidth=0` I can still can see some white lines, which polutes my final output when seen in pdf format.

I strongly believe this is caused by antialiasing, so I tried `antialiased=False`, as suggested by others. It works for raster images, but the pdf image still shows these lines.

Fortunately I found a similiar question for contour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263769/hide-contour-linestroke-on-pyplot-contourf-to-get-only-fills?noredirect=1&lq=1), which does:

```
for c in cnt.collections:
    c.set_edgecolor("face")
```

This answer looked very promising, but for 3d plots the object `Poly3DCollection` has no attribute `collections`.

Is there any workaround for 3d plots? I'm not proffiecient enough in Python, but I'm wondering if an analogous attribute to `collections` would be the answer

code to repro this issue:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = x**2 + y**2
s = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride = 1, cstride = 1, cmap='gray', linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
plt.savefig("3d.pdf")
```

Error when using `collections`:

```
AttributeError: 'Poly3DCollection' object has no attribute 'collections'
```

Thanks!